# Kofax 9. Does .Net Framework 4.0 COM objects work properly?

Tags: .net, com, kofax

Why Kofax Custom Modules and Workflow Agents (COM objects written in .Net 4.0 framework) fail with strange errors with Kofax (Access violation, methods not found e.t.c). When the same modules are compiled with .Net Framework 3.5 - everything works ok.

I guess is there a common reason for COM objects to fail under x86 host application (Kofax in my case) due to .Net Framework version they are compiled (4.0 doesn't work but 3.5 works ok)?

4.0 is installed on target workstation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You might make it work by putting this into the app config files of the Kofax modules:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   <requiredRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```